# Difference between Ruby methods

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between writing

```
def password=(password)
  @password = password
end
```

and

```
def password(password)
  @password = password
end
```

When should I use one form or the other?

Comment: Isn't is obvious? The method names differ.

Comment: @sawa when someone starts ruby, it takes a bit time to accept that `[]`, `=`, `?`, `!` can be a literal part of a function name. for ruby using `something=`  or `something_will_be_set_to` is same. but raison d'être why ruby prefers first style is purely aesthetic challenge (readability, expressing desire clearly etc.). and for sure, internal aesthetic concerns is not obvious on first run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions would assign `'secret'` to the `@password` variable.

The difference is how you would call that method to set a password later on. Your first example will need to be called like

```
user.password = 'secret'
```

Your second version needs the following syntax

```
user.password 'secret'
```

Clearly, the `password=` version is easier to read and to understand. Whereas the `password` (without the `=`) might be confused with a getter method. Therefore `password=` is more idiomatic.

As David Aldridge already pointed out there is the [`attr_writer`](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html#label-2) macro that generates exactly the code as your first example. Therefore

```
attr_writer :password
```

is the Ruby way to write this kind of setter methods.

Answer (score 1):

You should use neither.

To assign a value to an instance variable using a method of the same name, use `attr_writer`.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_writer